# Creating charts using HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xslt

Trying to achieve some column charts using HTML. So, it seams I'm close but I just cant get my column graph. What is missing with this?

Chart Dates should have years(2003,2004) on x-axis, and values #CarsSold on y-axis (37,63). Same way is other chart, only with few more elements.

Tnx

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type"  content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
    <link href="basic.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="visualize.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="visualize-light.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="visualize.jQuery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table border = "1" width = "100%">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>URL</th>
        <th>#CarsSold</th>
        <th>year</th>
        <th>Brands</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>PPP</td>
        <td>http://</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>
            <table id ="dates" style="margin:auto;border:solid; width:50%">
                <caption>Dates</caption>
                <thead><tr>
                    <th scope="col">2003</th>
                    <th scope="col">2004</th>
                </tr></thead>
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td>37</td>
                    <td>63</td>
                </tr></tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table id ="formats" style="margin:auto;border:solid; width:20%">
                <caption>Formats</caption>
                <thead><tr>
                    <th scope="col">fiat</th>
                    <th scope="col">merc</th>
                    <th scope="col">bmw</th>
                    <th scope="col">toyota</th>
                    <th scope="col">opel</th>
                </tr></thead>
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>31</td>
                    <td>33</td>
                    <td>19</td>
                    <td>14</td>
                </tr></tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
       $('#dates').visualize({width: '150px', height: '150px'});
    });
    $(function(){
       $('#formats').visualize({width: '150px',height: '150px'});
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:
I should get charts like this inside my table:
http://postimg.org/image/qv7co9lul/

well, code says what I have tried to use (css,jquery...). Anyhow?

Comment: Highcharts is a great javascript charting framework that can do advanced charts

Comment: You are so brave to plot charts in html using tables!! I will recommend d3 (or c3 if it is simple charts)

Comment: Made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9ug2keoL/4/

Comment: You have not described what you want and how the result differs from it. You have not included your CSS code. You have tagged the question with “html” only, even though it is apparently in CSS, JavaScript, and jQuery where the problem is.

Comment: This jsfiddle.net/9ug2keoL/4  is just what i want...maybe without this mini tables, once closest to charts. So, how to achieve this...I have a feeling that I miss something...i don't know how to connect this .js and .css with index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is close to desired solution, I mean it's what I want but just these brand names overlap probably because there is too small distance between  columns in my second chart. If anyone can fix it quickly it would be great. How to make it look nicer?

html + js.script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type"  content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
    <link href="visualize.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="visualize.jQuery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table border = "1" width = "100%">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>URL</th>
        <th>#CarsSold</th>
        <th>year</th>
        <th>Brands</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>PPP</td>
        <td>http://</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>
            <table id ="dates" style="display:none">
                <caption>Dates</caption>
                <thead><tr>
                    <th scope="col">2003</th>
                    <th scope="col">2004</th>
                </tr></thead>
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td>37</td>
                    <td>63</td>
                </tr></tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table id ="formats" style="display:none">
                <caption>Formats</caption>
                <thead><tr>
                    <th scope="col">fiat</th>
                    <th scope="col">merc</th>
                    <th scope="col">bmw</th>
                    <th scope="col">toyota</th>
                    <th scope="col">opel</th>
                </tr></thead>
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>31</td>
                    <td>33</td>
                    <td>19</td>
                    <td>14</td>
                </tr></tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
       $('#dates').visualize({width: '150px', height: '150px'});
    });
    $(function(){
       $('#formats').visualize({width: '150px',height: '150px'});
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

visualize.css:

```
    /*plugin styles*/
.visualize { border: 1px solid #888; position: relative; background: #fafafa; }
.visualize canvas { position: absolute; }
.visualize ul,.visualize li { margin: 0; padding: 0;}

/*table title, key elements*/
.visualize .visualize-info { padding: 3px 5px; background: #fafafa; border: 1px solid #888; position: absolute; top: -20px; right: 10px; opacity: .8; }
.visualize .visualize-title { display: block; color: #333; margin-bottom: 3px;  font-size: 1.1em; }
.visualize ul.visualize-key { list-style: none;  }
.visualize ul.visualize-key li { list-style: none; float: left; margin-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px; position: relative;}
.visualize ul.visualize-key .visualize-key-color { width: 6px; height: 6px; left: 0; position: absolute; top: 50%; margin-top: -3px;  }
.visualize ul.visualize-key .visualize-key-label { color: #000; }

/*pie labels*/
.visualize-pie .visualize-labels { list-style: none; }
.visualize-pie .visualize-label-pos, .visualize-pie .visualize-label { position: absolute;  margin: 0; padding:0; }
.visualize-pie .visualize-label { display: block; color: #fff; font-weight: bold; font-size: 1em; }
.visualize-pie-outside .visualize-label { color: #000; font-weight: normal; }

/*line,bar, area labels*/
.visualize-labels-x,.visualize-labels-y { position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; list-style: none; }
.visualize-labels-x li, .visualize-labels-y li { position: absolute; bottom: 0; }
.visualize-labels-x li span.label, .visualize-labels-y li span.label { position: absolute; color: #555;  }
.visualize-labels-x li span.line, .visualize-labels-y li span.line {  position: absolute; border: 0 solid #ccc; }
.visualize-labels-x li { height: 100%; }
.visualize-labels-x li span.label { top: 100%; margin-top: 5px; }
.visualize-labels-x li span.line { border-left-width: 1px; height: 100%; display: block; }
.visualize-labels-x li span.line { border: 0;} /*hide vertical lines on area, line, bar*/
.visualize-labels-y li { width: 100%;  }
.visualize-labels-y li span.label { right: 100%; margin-right: 5px; display: block; width: 100px; text-align: right; }
.visualize-labels-y li span.line { border-top-width: 1px; width: 100%; }
.visualize-bar .visualize-labels-x li span.label { width: 100%; text-align: center; }

/* page styles */
body { font-family: "Segoe UI", Frutiger,Tahoma,Helvetica,"Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif; font-size:62.5%;  }
table {  border-collapse: collapse; }
td, th { 
   text-align: center; 
   border: 1px solid #ddd; 
   padding:2px 5px; 
   }

caption {margin: 0 0 .5em; font-weight: bold; }


/*demo styles*/
table {width: 500px; height: 200px; margin-left: 30px; }
table.accessHide { position: absolute; left: -999999px; }
td, th {  font-size: 1.2em; padding: 2px; width: 13%; }
th { background-color:#f4f4f4; } 
caption { font-size: 1.5em;  }

/*visualize extension styles*/
.visualize { margin: 60px 0 0 30px; padding: 70px 40px 90px; background: #ccc url(../images/chartbg-vanilla.png) top repeat-x; border: 1px solid #ddd; -moz-border-radius: 12px; -webkit-border-radius: 12px; border-radius: 12px; }
.visualize canvas { border: 1px solid #aaa; margin: -1px; background: #fff; }
.visualize-labels-x, .visualize-labels-y { top: 70px; left: 40px; z-index: 100; }
.visualize-pie .visualize-labels { position: absolute; top: 70px; left: 40px; }
.visualize-labels-x li span.label, .visualize-labels-y li span.label { color: #444; font-size: 1.3em; padding-right: 5px; }
.visualize-labels-y li span.line { border-style: solid;  opacity: .7; }
.visualize .visualize-info { border: 0; position: static;  opacity: 1; background: none; }
.visualize .visualize-title { position: absolute; top: 20px; color: #333; margin-bottom: 0; left: 20px; font-size: 2.1em; font-weight: bold; }
.visualize ul.visualize-key { position: absolute; bottom: 15px; background: #eee; z-index: 10; padding: 10px 0; color: #aaa; width: 100%; left: 0;  }
.visualize ul.visualize-key li { font-size: 1.2em;  margin-left: 20px; padding-left: 18px; }
.visualize ul.visualize-key .visualize-key-color { width: 10px; height: 10px;  margin-top: -4px; }
.visualize ul.visualize-key .visualize-key-label { color: #333; }
```